# Error java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string

Tengo un Problema con este programa, funciona para que al introducir un texto como "234+312" convierta las cadenas en numeros y haga la operacion correspondiente, pero me sale un error

```
package Pruebas;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prueba {

 public static void main(String ...S) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    String ope;
    System.out.print ("Ingrese la operacion:");
    ope = sc.nextLine();
    String strNum1 = "", strNum2 = "";
    boolean centinela = false;
    char car = '\0', operador = '\0';
    double num1 = 0, num2 = 0, res = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i > ope.length()) {
        car = ope.charAt(i);
        if (car == '+' || car == '-' || car == '*' || car == '/') {
            operador = car;
            centinela = true;
        } else {
            if (centinela == false) {
                strNum1 = strNum1 + car;
            } else {
                strNum2 = strNum2 + car;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(strNum1);
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(strNum2);
    switch (operador) {
    case'+':
        res = num1 +num2;
        break;
    case'-':
        res = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case'*':
        res = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case'/':
        res = num1 / num2;
        break;  
    }
    System.out.print (res);
}



}
```

[image: el error que sale]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la siguiente línea:

```
num1 = Double.parseDouble(strNum1);
num2 = Double.parseDouble(strNum2);
```

Ya que el error dice que el parámetro que recibe es un String vacio, es decir no tiene valor alguno por tanto no puede castearlo a tipo Double. Esto ocurre por el código que tienes acá:

```
String strNum1 = "", strNum2 = "";
```

Y luego aquí

```
if (centinela == false) {
    strNum1 = strNum1 + car;
} else {
    strNum2 = strNum2 + car;
}
```

Por alguna razón en la iteración del while nunca entra a la asginación de strNum1.

Y eso es porque la condición está mal escrita, debería ser así:

```
while (i < ope.length()) { //Simplemente cambié el ">" que tenias por "<"
```

Con esto debe solucionarse el problema :)